# Should i put nickname avatar into user access token?

Tags: token, jwt

Should I put user's nickname and avatar into user's access token like jwt? what's the best practice?

Comment: Think about it yourself. What is the token representing? The user itself or information how to validate the user?

Comment: I think the token represent the information used to authenticate the user.

Comment: Alright, so with that in mind. Do you need a username to validate the token? Possibly, it depends on how the server handles the token, this can definately be the case. Often the "sub" claim of the token is used for this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2 The avatar on the other hand, would you need that for a similar reason? I would say that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- sub Subject - This holds the identifier for the token (defaults to
  user id)
- iat Issued At - When the token was issued (unix timestamp)
- exp Expiry - The token expiry date (unix timestamp)
- nbf Not Before - The earliest point in time that the token can be
  used (unix timestamp)
- iss Issuer - The issuer of the token (defaults to the request url)
- jti JWT Id - A unique identifier for the token (md5 of    the sub and
  iat claims)

**Just put the user's uniquely identifies into the subject claim.**